# Regex to delete all leading blank lines

Tags: regular-expression

Is there a Vim regex to delete all leading blank lines in the file?

```
text
more text

some more text
```

Should become:

```
text
more text

some more text
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following should do the job:

```
:%s/\%^\_\s*\n//
```

Here is an explanation:

- `\%^` match the beginning of the file
- `\_\s` match any space character including new line
- `*` repeat the match
- `\n` match the last new line

I include the `\n` to not match the leading space on the first non white-space line (line that that is only made of white-spaces)

Remark: If by blank line you mean empty line the regex is more simple:

```
:%s/\%^\n*//
```

Comment: This only removes a blank first line not subsequent blank lines.
@mas answer works if there are no spaces in the line, not possible to tell from the question. If there are then `:g/^\s\+/d` will work on every line

Comment: Not in the test I made. The `\_\s` item match new line and the `*` make it work for multiple lines

Comment: I tested it and it works. It  does remove subsequent blank lines.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)

Answer (score 5):

Probably the most concise way to do this is with a [range](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-ranges) and the [`:delete`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Adelete) command:

```
:1,/\S/-1d
             # Explanation
             # -----------
         d   # Delete all the lines
:1,          # in the range that starts at the beginning of the file
       -1    # and ends one line before
   /\S/      # the first line containing a non-whitespace character
```

If you don't want to delete whitespace-only lines it's even shorter:

```
:1,/./-1d

        d   # Delete all the lines
:1,         # in the range that starts at the beginning of the file
      -1    # and ends one line before
   /./      # the first line containing anything
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the method I use:

```
:g/^$/d
```

Comment: That will remove *all* blank lines though, not just the ones at the start of the file. The way I read the question, it should only remove blank lines at the start of the file.

Answer (score 1):

On the off chance that one or more of the lines isn't exactly blank, but contains whitespace, this variant on @mas answer works:

```
:g/^\s*$/d
```

You asked about *leading* blank lines. That implies to me that you don't want to delete any lines that come either between text-containing lines or after them. If that's the case, you want to put a range between the <kbd>:</kbd> and the <kbd>g</kbd>. In your sample's case, where it appears to me there are two blank lines, it'd look like:

```
:1,2g/^\s*$/d
```

Comment: If you already know how many blank lines there are, there's no need to use `:g` at all: `:1,2d`. Although note that in the sample, there's actually only one blank line, so `:1d`.

Comment: @Rich I agree. Deleting blank lines need be no more complicated than deleting non-blank lines.

Comment: I'm not sure if I made my point clearly. You wrote: "If that's the case, you want to put a range between the `:` and the `g`". But if you add a range specifying where the blank lines are, then you don't need the `g` or the regular expression at all.

Comment: @Rich Dang, you're right. I even removed the `g` when I was testing it, but forgot to do so when I typed the answer.